# Lost my "Keyboard Shortcuts" (and I had a bunch) when switched from 5s to 6s - anyway to get them back?

Tags: keyboard, ios, iphone

I got myself a new 6s and I noticed that all of my keyboard shortcuts (now called Text Replacement) are gone! Sux. Anyone else have this issue and have you found a way to restore them?

Comment: They should be in your last iTunes backup [possibly requiring the backup to be encrypted, same as for passwords etc, but not certain about that]. Mine all ported from 5S to 6S correctly. I never trust iCloud for updates/phone swaps, but have never lost any work doing it via iTunes.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I am on the latest iOS 9 beta version which won't let me revert to a backup from a previous version of iOS. That is the issue with me  getting in there and trying to load it from a previous backup. Any thoughts?

Comment: My first thought would be 'never install a beta OS on a mission-critical device' ;) I guess you'd have to wipe & install to current iOS & hope that's what the backup was done on [or earlier, they will go uphill, just not downhill]

Comment: good point. I could give that a whirl. i had quite a few shortcuts and re-entering them is not something I want to do. thx.